# Rails: If Foo has_many :bars, do all :bars need to belong_to a Foo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I'm working on an app that has a lot of photos in it, which are contributed by users. The photo-sharing aspect is the primary purpose of the app.

Sometimes it's helpful to create featured "Collections" of photos. So, this is easy enough in ActiveRecord: `Collection has_many :photos` and `Photo belongs_to :collection`.

The question I have is, for an 'ordinary' photo that doesn't belong to a special collection, should I:

**A. Not have it belong to any collection at all.** ie: `photo.collection == nil`

-or-

**B. Create a generic "Community Collection" that holds every photo.** ie by default `photo.collection == 'Community'`

I am also considering whether this should be a HABTM relationship.

Feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: One more question, for bonus points: what ( if any ) behavior do I need to be wary of if the "uncollected" photos are not part of a generic collection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you're going to do with your uncollected photos, really.  If you want the ability to show the uncollected photos with the same action you use to show a collection, then you'll want to have that generic collection.  Otherwise, I'd leave it nil; I don't like mixing "seed" data with user data in the same table (which you'd be doing with the "uncollected" collection) - it's too easy to accidentally wipe out your user data when reseeding.

Should it be a HABTM relationship?  Again, depends on how you want to use it.  If there's a good chance you'll want photos to belong to multiple collections, go for it.

And the things that I've seen mentioned here that I would *not* do:  Adding a 'ptype' attribute to tell singletons from collected photos (waste of DB space - you can already get that info by calling `photo.collection_id.nil?`); and using polymorphic models (you don't want singleton photos to behave drastically different, I assume, so this is added complexity for little to no benefit).

Named scopes, though, are a great idea, and will be particularly useful if you don't have the "uncollected" collection to find your singletons by:

```
#Apologies for the Rails 2.3 code - it's what I know...
named_scope :singletons, {:conditions => {:collection_id => nil}}
```

Or the HABTM version:

```
named_scope :singletons, lambda {
    {:conditions => ['NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM collections_photos WHERE photo_id = ?)', self.id]}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

What about using a ptype attribute ? You could have photo.ptype = 'collection' or photo.ptype = 'single'. This way you would be able to identify each photo by that type. Moreover, you can make it even more elegant by using a scope on the photos and specify collection_photos scope or single_photos.

Another possibility is polymorphic models. Have a photo model and a collectionPhoto and singlePhoto model that are using it.

Comment: So, I've never heard of ptype before. Is that just an attribute on the photo model, and I use it to tell if a photo is in a collection or not?

Comment: yes just a name :) You just can't use type because it's a Rails keyword; that's why i use ptype, but it can be anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would only set the collection property when it belonged to a collection. Just be sure that your view code can handle this case.